# How to augment data in tensorflow tfrecords?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-slim

I am storing my data using tfrecords and I read them as tensors using `Dataset` API and then I use the `Estimator` API to perform training. Now, I want to do online data-augmentation on each item in the dataset, but after trying for a while I cannot find a way out to do it. I want randomly flipping, randomly rotation and other manipulators.

I am following the instructions given in [this](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/18_TFRecords_Dataset_API.ipynb) tutorial with a custom estimator which is the my CNN and I am not sure where the data augmentation step occurs.

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far? That would help others understand what you need and how you failed.

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot Check updated question.

Answer (score 7):

Using TFRecords doesn't prevent you from doing data augmentation.

Following the [tutorial](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/18_TFRecords_Dataset_API.ipynb) you linked in your comment, here is what roughly happens:

- You create the dataset from the TFRecords files, and parse the file to get an `image` and a `label`

```py
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(parse)
```

- You can now apply a new preprocessing function to do some data augmentation during training

```py
# Only do it when we are training
if train:
    dataset = dataset.map(train_preprocess)
```

- The `train_preprocess` function can be something like this:

```py
def train_preprocess(image, label):
    flip_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    # Other transformations...
    return flip_image, label
```

Comment: Your `train_preprocess` function is limited to the functions defined like `tf.image.random_*` e.g. There is no way to do a random rotation using the functions in `tf.image`.

Comment: Also, I don't want to make a chain of transformations. I want to do one transformation at a time i.e. when I do flipping -- I don't want to do rotations. You can argue why, but that's how I want to learn to do it. The problem that I faced was it that I couldn't find a neat way to place if-else blocks because it gets run once when the graph is generated and then uses the same transformation always. I was looking at `tf.cond` but wasn't sure what the right practice is.

Comment: You can use [`tf.contrib.image.rotate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/rotate) for rotation. For your second comment, maybe take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299345/using-if-conditions-inside-a-tensorflow-graph)

Comment: I am not sure how to use `tf.contrib.image.rotate` because the `angles` argument needs to be randomly generated for each image at runtime.

Comment: Also, `tf.cond` works good for 2 branches only -- if I have n branches, it becomes really ugly. I was looking for a neater alternative.

Comment: These are all great questions that would be better in their own stackoverflow post. Take a look at tf.case for the switch statements.